# Discrepancy of Hadamard type matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $H$ be $\{-1,+1\}$ Hadamard matrix of size $2$ and $J$ be the same size all $1$ matrix. Let $W$ be $\frac{H+J}{2}$. Is the discrepancy of $W^{\otimes k}$ atmost $\sqrt{k^{-1}}$?

Comment: There is more than one thing called "discrepancy" that applies to matrices. Do you mean the discrepancy used in communication complexity?

Comment: @SashoNikolov Yes.

Comment: Your 'Hadamard type matrix" is just the disjointness matrix. The discrepancy is at least $(2k + 1)^{-1}$ but I am not sure what the tight upper bound is.